# How to get more precise float type in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, floating-point, precision

How to get a float type in Python, that can have more digits after decimal point? By more digits I mean very big amount of then (like hundreds or thousands), so decimal type won't be right. I also tried with GMPY2, but I can't even download this to my Python. Is there any library that has types like this?

Python 3.8 | Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Did you try the numpy library? That supports float16, float32, float64.

Comment: Yes, but they aren't precise that much as I need.

Comment: Use the decimal module. Please see my answer

Comment: I assume you are using the version of Python 3 that is included with Ubuntu. You can install `gmpy2` using the following command from the terminal: `sudo apt install python3-gmpy2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Decimal module. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 123  # Setting precision to 123 digits
>>> decimal.Decimal(10) / decimal.Decimal(3)
# Can't fit the answer here, so not showing. Try yourself

>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 1000  # Setting precision to 1000 digits
>>> decimal.Decimal(10) / decimal.Decimal(3)
# Can't fit the answer here again, so not showing. Try yourself
```

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for the decimal module.

Note that, depending on the memory available on your device, the highest possible precision you can use can differ.